# Subproject dependencies in pants

Tags: python, pants

I am new to using [pantsbuild](http://www.pantsbuild.org/) and I can't seem to find any good questions, answers, or documentation around my dillema.

I have a Pants project which should be buildable on its own. It has its own `pants` and `pants.ini` file as well as all `BUILD` files containing paths relative to the project root (where `pants.ini` is). This project is hosted on GitHub.

I'd like to use this project as a dependency in a second project. I've chosen to use git submodules to do this. Now, I have a layout like the following:

```
path
├── pants
├── pants.ini
├── projectA
│   └── src
│       └── python
|           └── main
│               ├── BUILD
│               └── main.py
└── projectB
    ├── pants
    ├── pants.ini
    └── src
        └── python
            ├── libA
            |   ├── BUILD
            |   └── lib.py
            └── libB
                ├── BUILD
                └── lib.py
```

Naturally, I am looking to use projectB's BUILD targets from within projectA, so in projectA's `BUILD`, I have something of the sort:

```
dependencies = [ "projectB/src/python:libA" ]
```

This is all well and good. However, since projectB is an independent project, it's `src/python/libA/BUILD` file contains something of the sort:

```
dependencies = [ "src/python:libB" ]
```

Because of this, projectB can indeed be built independently. However, when trying to build projectA, the build targets from projectB search starting from projectA's project root, for instance:

```
Exception Message: libB was not found in BUILD files from path/src/python
```

Does pantsbuild have any clean way to handle these subproject dependencies? Or would I be forced to alter the BUILD files of the subproject in order to fit them within my project layout (Causing the project to be unbuildable independently)?

Any solutions or advice is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the functionality I was hoping for was not supported by pants. At first, I followed the advice of a Yi Cheng in the comments and created a script to replace all subproject BUILD rules with those that are in relation to the root project. That script can be found here: https://github.com/brandonio21/pants-subproject-prep

The script was pretty limited, however, and was far from a workable solution. I have since changed pants upstream to support the behavior. The PR was here: https://github.com/pantsbuild/pants/pull/4088

Now, if you have a subproject within another pants project, building the root project with `--subproject-roots=["path/to/subproject1_root", "path/to/subproject2_root"]` (Or specifying the option in `pants.ini`) will build the subproject from the proper subproject root

Answer (score 0):

> This is all well and good. However, since projectA is an independent project, it's src/python/libA/BUILD file contains something of the sort:
>
> > dependencies = [ "src/python:libB" ]

iiuc `src/python:libB` needs to be `projectB/src/python:libB`. All target paths in the repo should be relative to the build root which is `path` in your example.

Comment: This is correct. In order for the project to work properly, projectB/src/python/libA/BUILD should contain `dependencies = [ "projectB/src/python:libB" ]`

Comment: Woops, pressed enter too early. However, my point is, projectB is an independent project. I would like it to be buildable on its own without any knowledge of the fact that it is in another project.

Comment: Just noticed there are two sets of `pants` and `pants.ini`, but only one should be allowed at the build root. e.g. in projectB, you would have to convert target paths w.r.t to the new build root.

The behavior is also funky here because pants determines build root based on where `pants` executable is located.

Comment: Right. I was hoping there might be some way to overcome this, especially since projectB does not have any dependencies on projectA.

Comment: I do not see any shortcuts per se, but it should be relatively easy to write a script replacing `src/python` with `projectB/src/python` in BUILD files.